# Allow parent to handle mouse event

Tags: java, swing

I added a `JPanel` to a `JRadioButton` - so that I may display whatever I want in the radio button.

This all worked as expected. But to allow for text wrapping, I used a `JTextArea` and added it to the `JPanel` contained within the radio button.

Now I have an issue where, if the user clicks on the `JTextArea`, then the `JTextArea` consumes the `mouseEvent` and as a result there is no response from the radio button (it doesn't 'select').

Is there a way get the `JTextArea` to ignore the mouse click, so that the parent may handle it instead?

I tried add the `JTextArea`'s listeners to the `radioButton` instead.

I also tried to remove its listeners completely, but both these attempts failed.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Strong beware**

Most JSomething are not *meant* to be used as containers even though it's possible - the outcome of doing it anyway is more or less visually and behaviourally undetermined!

That said, did it recently, to implement something similar to a Windows task dialog. If the requirement includes keeping the button clickable (and why else would you mis-use it as a container :-) the main problem (layout apart) is to make all added components completely mouse-transparent. Which is more difficult than can be expected. The minimum is to not allow adding of mouseListeners and disable the acceptance of mouseEvents:

```
final JTextArea area = new JTextArea("replacement ..") {

    @Override
    public synchronized void addMouseListener(MouseListener l) {
        LOG.info("adding here ...?");
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void addMouseMotionListener(
            MouseMotionListener l) {
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void addMouseWheelListener(
            MouseWheelListener l) {
    }

    @Override
    public void addNotify() {
        disableEvents(AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK | 
                AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK | 
                AWTEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL_EVENT_MASK);
        super.addNotify();
    }
};
```

Plus make sure it's not focusable

```
area.setEditable(false);
area.setFocusable(false);
area.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
```

Plus unregister dragging and tooltips

```
ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().unregisterComponent(area);
area.setDragEnabled(false);
```

Nevertheless, there might still be surprises ahead, f.i. call the following twice (that is disable and enable again), which will internally re-enable mouseEvent:

```
area.setAutoscrolls(!area.getAutoscrolls());
```

So at the end of the day, we might get away with it - but never be entirely certain that we succeeded.

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for the quick response. Your solution worked perfectly! Also, thank you for the warning. I will try and find a better way of doing this when I get a chance :)

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Create and add your own MouseListener to TextArea

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
JTextArea t = new JTextArea("line \n line");
t.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
p.add(t);
jRadioButton1.add(p);
jRadioButton1.addMouseListener(new MyRadioButtonMouseListener());
```

And in the MyMouseListener Dispatch event

```
private class MyMouseListener implements MouseListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        Component source = (Component) e.getSource();
        source.getParent().getParent().dispatchEvent(e); // 2x getParent() because JTextArea->JPanel->JRadio
    }
    .
    .
    .
    }
```

And finally RadioButtonMouseListener

```
private class MyRadioButtonMouseListener implements MouseListener {

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("CLICK ON RADIOBUTTON !!");
    }
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for the response. This seems like a good solution as well. Unfortunately the code is super complex at the moment, making this solution a bit more difficult to implement. Thanks again :)